# Partition of sets of monomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, graph-colorings, enumerative-combinatorics

Given a degree $d>0$ and $x_1,\dots,x_n$, consider the set $S$ of monomials
\begin{equation*}
  x_1^{i_1} \cdots x_n^{i_n}
\end{equation*}
with $0\leq i_j\leq d$ for $1\leq j\leq n$ (the exponents are constrained to a hypercube in the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n$).

Are there results on the number of ways in which $S$ can be partitioned into $k$ disjoint sets, so that no two monomials in the same set divide each other? Alternatively one can ask for sets of integer vectors where no two vectors are comparable in the lexicographic order.

Comment: For the minimum $k=nd+1$ there is just 1. The general case seems very hard. For $k=nd+2$ it is the number of ways to pick a single set meeting your condition (which isn't one of the sets from the previous condition). Maybe try to solve that for $d=2$ or $n=2$ first.